# Apache URL redirection not working with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect the URL:

```
http://example.com/site to http://example.com/~username/site
```

I have the following in my *httpd.conf* file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/site/(.*) /~username/site/$1 [PT]
```

but this does not seem to be working. It tries to look for `/site` under `/var/www/site/` and fails. What am I doing wrong? FYI, I have also tried with:

```
RewriteRule ^/site/(.*)$ /~username/site/$1 [PT]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/site/(.*) /~username/site/$1 [PT]
```

That code should be going into `.htaccess`, not `httpd.conf`. Try that, and it should fix your issue.